# datatables add class to filters

Tags: jquery, html, datatable, bootstrap-4

I am currently seeking a method to add an additional custom class to the jQuery datatables filters (**Records per page** and **Search**)

These items render as follow:

```
<div id="DataTables_Table_0_length" class="dataTables_length">
    <label>
        <select size="1" name="DataTables_Table_0_length" 
                aria-controls="DataTables_Table_0">
            <option value="10" selected="selected">10</option>
            <option value="25">25</option><option value="50">50</option>
            <option value="100">100</option>
        </select>
        records per page
    </label>
</div>
```

and

```
<div class="dataTables_filter" id="DataTables_Table_0_filter">
    <label>
        Search: <input type="text" aria-controls="DataTables_Table_0">
    </label>
</div>
```

Does anyone know how I can best add an additional class to each of them? Some advise would be as usual very much appreciated.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Check out http://legacy.datatables.net/styling/custom_classes. DataTables has a slightly complicated way to override the CSS classes for some of the core elements. Here's one way

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var extensions = {
        "sFilter": "dataTables_filter custom_filter_class",
        "sLength": "dataTables_length custom_length_class"
    }
    // Used when bJQueryUI is false
    $.extend($.fn.dataTableExt.oStdClasses, extensions);
    // Used when bJQueryUI is true
    $.extend($.fn.dataTableExt.oJUIClasses, extensions);
    $('#example').dataTable();
});
```

Check out a working example here: http://jsfiddle.net/k2ava/3/.

Comment: The problem I see with this is that it's not the `<div>` itself you want to style usually, but the `<input>` tag itself. It doesn't look like we have a way of amending these.

Comment: @mpdc I need the way you wanted too. I've added the input tag in css. Check this [JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/k2ava/102/)

Comment: If someone looking for just adding a class to input field alone, do it simply with jquery like, `$(".dataTables_filter input").addClass('custom-class)`

Answer (score 17):

i'm use DataTable 1.10.2 and i use :

```
$.extend( $.fn.dataTableExt.oStdClasses, {
    "sFilterInput": "form-control",
    "sLengthSelect": "form-control"
});
```

I go through the extend function instead of jquery.

Answer (score 3):

This can also be easily done with jQuery using fnDrawCallback.  Here I add two classes to style for Bootstrap

```
fnDrawCallback: function( oSettings ) {
$('div#oTable_length select, div#oTable_filter input').addClass("form-control input-sm");
},
```